# How to setup our server as an IPFS node?

Tags: ipfs

I have a server and wish to setup it as an IPFS node. In fact, I wish to contribute to the IPFS ecosystem and have permanently pinning a file. Would you please help me in details? How to setup my server as an IPFS node?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Install IPFS

```
wget https://dist.ipfs.io/go-ipfs/v0.4.14/go-ipfs_v0.4.14_linux-amd64.tar.gz -O go-ipfs.tar.gz
tar xvfz go-ipfs.tar.gz
sudo cp go-ipfs/ipfs /usr/local/bin/
```

Run the daemon

```
ipfs init
ipfs daemon &
```

You'll now be part of the IPFS P2P network